# I don´t know what version of Python I have, and problem coding my first website

Tags: python, cmd

I have installed the latest version of python (3.7.3)

When I go to cmd and I put `py`, it says my version is 3.7.3. But the problem comes when i put `python` or `python --version`, because it says that my version is 2.7.10. And i don´t know why.

---

I´m learning how to do my first website, and i´m just following what the tutorial says. I don´t know if the version of python is the cause of the problem, but i tell you what happens to me appart from not knowing what version i have.

I´m using Visual Studio Code and the guy from the tutorial said that we had to have at least a version of python over 3, and to find this out we have to write on CMD `python --version`. Then we had to know what version of pip we have putting `pip --version`.

Now I´ll show you the code he did and I copied, I had to install flask from CMD putting `pip install flask`.

So when I go to CMD to run this as the youtuber did, putting `cd Desktop` then `cd NoFear` (NoFear is the name of the folder) and finally `python index.py`. I got the following output:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\NoFear>python index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask

C:\Users\Usuario>py
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

C:\Users\Usuario>python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

C:\Users\Usuario>python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: You should create a virtual environment to avoid problems with multiple versions of Python. [This article](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) might help.

Comment: I have added an answer to your question, but I strongly suggest you to read the article I have mentioned in my previous comment or if you prefer to look for further information about virtual environments in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type Py -3 index.py in cmd instead of typing python index.py. I hope this helps

Comment: thanks for answering, but it says " "Python3" is not recognized as an executable internal or external command, program or batch file.

Comment: Try this: py -3 index.py

Answer (score 0):

You have two versions of python so uninstall the older version first

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual environment that will isolate your Python dependencies. Because you have stated you are using Python 3.7.3, you can create a virtual environment by running the following command:

```
$ python3 -m venv .venv
```

Then you can activate it by using:

```
$ source .venv/bin/activate
```

Then if you run `python` in the terminal, you will start Python 3.7.3 because your virtual environment has been created using this version of Python.

Finally, if you want to deactivate the virtual environment just run:

```
$ deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall a your other python versions or if you want to keep them you can rearrange the path. That being said I would recommend looking into creating virtual environments.

*1)* In the bottom left of windows search for: **environment variables**
[image]
*2)* Select *Environment Variables...* on the bottom right.
*3)* Select the `Path` variable on the top (or bottom if there is not one on the top).
*4)* Move python3 above python2.7 and save.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe get atom cause you are working in IDLE and i had the same problem each time you want to use code form IDLE on other software you cannot run it because of the lines on top 
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information. 
you have to take them of or use virtual studio or atom or oder IDE, i think.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Using a different editor will not solve the OP's issue so this answer will likely get downvoted, which you should try to avoid because it affects your stackoverflow reputation.  If you delete the answer the downvotes will not count against you.